# Passing matrices to glsl just won't work?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

Im currently using lwjgl and programming glsl 1.20.

This is how the code that tries to send the 4x4 float matrix to the shaders looks like:

```
    int normalMatrixLocation = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(handlers.ShaderHandler.get().getShader("sphere"), "normalMatrix");
    tempFloatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    tempFloatBuffer.put(helpers.Matrix.doubleToFloat4x4(normalMatrix.getArray()));
    tempFloatBuffer.rewind();
    ARBShaderObjects.glUniformMatrix4ARB(normalMatrixLocation, false, tempFloatBuffer);
```

The helper funciton looks like this:

```
    public static float[] doubleToFloat4x4(double[][] dArray) {
        float[] newFloat = new float[16];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                newFloat[j+4*i] = (float)dArray[i][j];
            }
        }
        return newFloat;
    }
```

And in the shader i have the following so that i will be able to use it inte the shaders different functions:

```
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
```

Though this uniform is always an empty 4x4 matrix...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check that `normalMatrixLocation` is a legitimate value? What does `rewind` do? Did you confirm that the `tempFloatBuffer` is not an empty matrix before calling `glUniformMatrix4ARB`?

Comment: You are not using GLSL 1.20. I know this because all of your calls end in ARB, which means you are using the ARB_shader_objects extension, which doesn't allow GLSL 1.20. Or if it does, it only works by accident. Don't use GLSL as an extension; use it as a core feature (no ARB suffix).

Comment: Thank you for the answers!
@JimBuck normalMatrixLocation is equal to 0 wich seams to be fine, rewind puts the internal itterators pointer to position 0.
I have confirmed that there is indeed data in the tempFloatBuffer when i call glUniformMatrix4ARB.
@NicolBolas I have specified `#version 120` in the top of my shader-files, are you saying that instead of using the arb surfix while using the classes from the library org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBShaderObjects should i use the corresponding functions in the library org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20?

Comment: Okay, thats very strange, after i tested the normalMatrixLocation and tested with out ARB and all that i reverted the code to how it looked before (i think) and now it just works... don't know what i changed but now it workes apparently!
Thanks for the help and i'm sorry that i can't find what the error was so that others won't have to have this problem.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: where have you found that ARB_shader_objects doesn't allow GLSL 1.20? The specification states only that it is written against GLSL 1.10, but it doesn't say when it is applicable!

Comment: The part where GLSL 1.20 allows for types like `mat3x4`, but ARB_shader_objects doesn't actually have functions to upload uniforms of that type. ARB_shader_objects should never be used, period. Not unless you are supporting truly old hardware. It's old and outdated. Just use GLSL as a core feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
uniform mat4x4 matrixName;
```

It's 'mat4x4' not 'mat4', as far as I can tell.

Also, sending float buffers requires the use of a bytebuffer and the ByteOrder class. My code looks like:

```
 qbuffer.rewind();

    ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    int qLocation = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(shaderProgram, "q");
    ARBShaderObjects.glUniformMatrix4ARB(qLocation, 
false, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(qbuffer).flip());
```

convoluted, yes, but it ensures native order.

Comment: 'mat4' is correct. Only non-square matrices describe both dimensions.

Comment: I say mat4x4 because it is indeed what I have been using. If what you say is true, this is well and good. You may edit my answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

The glUniform functions affect the current program. Make sure you call glUseProgramARB(myProgramObj) before calling glUniform.

Comment: There is no actual glUniform function, I said glUniform to encompass all of the many variants of glUniform (1f/4f/Matrix4f/etc). Obviously if you are using the ARB_shader_objects you would use the ARB versions of the glUniform functions.